# Google Charts Visualization Remove Numbers in X-axis

Tags: charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I used a sample from google charts. My code for it is:

```
   <script>

    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);

function drawCurveTypes() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Person 1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Person 2');

        data.addRows(9);

        data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(2010, 1, 1));
        data.setValue(0, 1, 215);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 215);

        data.setValue(1, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 1));
        data.setValue(1, 2, 213);

        data.setValue(2, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 4));
        data.setValue(2, 2, 213);

        data.setValue(3, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 8));
        data.setValue(3, 2, 213);


        data.setValue(4, 0, new Date(2010, 3, 1));
        data.setValue(4, 2, 220);

        data.setValue(5, 0, new Date(2010, 4, 1));
        data.setValue(5, 2, 190);

      var options = {
        {#chartArea:{ width:"100%", height:"100%"},#}
        title: "Persons Performance over Time",
        height: 500,
        width: 1300,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Scores'
        },
        series: {
          1: {curveType: 'function'}
        },

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }


    </script>
```

Im getting a result however it is mixed with the supposed to be X axis. My X axis is supposed to be dates because it is a time series data, scores of persons through time

[image]

I only want the date on my x-axis how do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the format of the x-axis in the options.

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for but the following would format as 07/23/2021...

```
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
      title: 'Time'
    },
```

**EDIT**

if you want to remove the labels, use the following option...

```
    hAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none',
      title: 'Time'
    },
```

Comment: thanks for your help and this one as well. However  I just want to remove the measure if I cant remain it as numbers. I tried changing the format but they just written on top with each other and it doesnt look good. Is there a way to just remove X labels? So its cleaner?